# Protect HTML in Comment

Tags: html, security, comments

In wordpress comments system, it work HTML. I want to protect inserting HTML in wordpress comment system.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your functions.php. I'm not sure if this does any pre-processing though.

```
add_filter('comment_text', 'wp_filter_nohtml_kses');
```